# CSS: left:auto is not overriding left:0

Tags: css

I am using `left: auto;` in the hope of overriding `left: 0;` but it is not working (see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9esrq86u/7/)) - I want `<header class="h1...">` to be center aligned.

HTML:

```
<div class="root">
  <header class="h1 header-opacity-enabled sticky-enabled sticky-no-topbar menu-animation-enabled hover-delay-enabled sticky-collapse sticky-opacity-enabled with-search-box with-cart-box lr-mi-with-widget-visible sticky" data-sticky-trigger-position="400" data-menu-slidedown-duration="400" data-menu-slideup-duration="500" data-menu-fadein-duration="300" data-menu-fadeout-duration="400" style="top: 0px;">
    <section class="main-header">
      <div>
        <div itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" itemscope="itemscope" class="title">
          <div class="logo-wrapper"> <a class="logo" href="https://websitetechnology.dev/" itemprop="url"> <img alt="Doig Website Technology" src="https://websitetechnology.dev/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/logo3-blue.png" itemprop="logo" height="77"> </a>
            <h3>Website Engineering, Optimisation &amp; Advertising</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="shopping-bag">
        <div class="widget woocommerce widget_shopping_cart">
          <div class="widget_shopping_cart_content">
            <div class="wrap">
              <p class="empty-item">There are no items in your cart.</p>

              <!-- end product list --> 

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <div class="s-801"></div>
    <div class="s-981"></div>
  </header>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.h1.sticky.sticky-opacity-enabled .main-header {
    background-color: #FFFF00;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 801px) {
.root header.sticky-enabled.sticky {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1236px;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: calc(1070px + 10%);
}
.root header.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
}
```

[Live site here](https://websitetechnology.com.au/). Scroll half way down the page until the sticky `<header>` pops down from the top of the window.

`left: auto;` is being applied, yet the `<header>' is stuck to the left side of the screen. This`` needs to be center aligned.

Can you help please?

Comment: How about adding `text-align:center`? Not sure if you want all of header contents to be center aligned!

Comment: Whats it ment to override? You haven't shown us that.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9esrq86u/8/ is this what you want?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9esrq86u/7/ you want like this fiddle?

Comment: @SandeepNayak I'd like the yellow header to be centered.

Comment: @AhsanAzizAbbasi I'd like the yellow header to be centered.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7ycbp71u/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have try to solved you and attached screenshot please find it. screenshot will help you to solved your issue.

Thanks,[image]

Comment: Thanks Rushi. Limiting `.root` to 1236px and centering `.root` was the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It must be because [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). In a few words:

> Specificity is the means by which browsers decide which CSS property
>   values are the most relevant to an element and, therefore, will be
>   applied. Specificity is based on the matching rules which are composed
>   of CSS selectors of different sorts.

If you give more specific selector, you can override the settings.
In Example, a more specific selector then your would be:

```
div.root header.sticky {
```

or

```
body div.root header.sticky {
```

...

This could help: [Specificity calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/)

Also, if you view in Chrome i.e. you can see if a css settings was overriden by being marked as struck through

[image]

Comment: On my development website, `left: auto;` is [being applied](https://i.imgur.com/xd6eljJ.png), yet the `<header>' is stuck to the left side of the screen.

Comment: [Live site here](https://websitetechnology.com.au/). Scroll half way down the page until the sticky <header> pops down from the top of the window. This <header> needs to be center aligned.

Comment: Live site's `style.css` now the same as development site's `style.css`.

Answer (score 0):

put your header inside this section

```
<section style="padding: 0;max-width: calc(1070px + 10%);margin: 0 auto;">
           <!--- put your header section here ---->
</section>
```